# Get subset of Union type based on Array values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following types:

```js
// All possible values
type Alphabet = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' // ... etc

// Value transformation
type ComputedAlphabet<A extends Alphabet> = {[k in A]: true}

let x: ComputedAlphabet<'a' | 'b'>; // it correctly expects: {a: true, b: true}
```

I'd like to have a function type that takes an array of Alphabet and compute their values:

```js
type TransformAlphabet=(chars: Alphabet[]) => ComputedAlphabet<how to get subset of Alphabet based on `chars`???>
```

Ideally, I would like to write a call like this and have the type inferred correctly:

```js
let transform: TransformAlphabet
transform(['a']) // should infer {a: true} as a return type
```

Of course, the first thing I tried is to use Generics but didn't know how to make the Generic type optional while producing correct types:

```js
type TransformAlphabet<A extends Alphabet>=(chars: A[]) => ComputedAlphabet<A>
```

That works if I manually pass the `A` generic type on call which is not practical in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost got it:

```
type TransformAlphabet=<A extends Alphabet>(chars: A[]) => ComputedAlphabet<A>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBtNAHB7AzoglgI0gU1ANwIaQCumiAUAC4Ces2UsAFnmpuaALygDkenoAPlzS8BnAMbCuAEwmdMvEKAB0y0C1GlSCgGoFiocgCc8AO0QAzeAYC2ecinjGK1bAGF4V2IXKZJdRs3IAHnBVAA9vY0lECEgGJhYAPnZQAG8AbQBrUBRjCABdAC59A2IAXw0sVlCitw8vHz94oO4ZIQSAblAFFFZRSwNMUXJISjCaIcQilLwiw2IAGlA0WZLMcs1gKhpQABUjUwtrRoC2AApRRgNJmLiAtLyASnYk2s9vX1j-FkD6eAB3fTwUAAcxYoEQhDQiDB8DMNy+rDQeGhklADlAAAMLngrhiAPwEhIaJzbPYmcyWKzHFhsYJhCJReFNBLnS7XcD3J5sF7uN4NT5NYJE0iVYrkw5WIpkg6U6msDisnGILlJFIaUCgAbkQgGXLYq6KAaSQiiTCnU54USiRb6lWpUgajVanW5NWOx3KRSW60O92gNL6wrFBa+jXlMOLFKlUDImPGSgPdqkcp9UysLIcQziymnNItR5dMCIX6ESConJmTAGVIzYNrGPRPCalgu-TOIA)

Comment: I've added a link.